# If the wrong credentials are submitted, program throws error

Tags: c#, mysql, exception

Regarding security this is a dirty prototype, hence the no hash salts for the passwords.

I am testing some c# MySQL code, and I when the  correct credentials have been sent to the database, the program returns the value 1, which means correct.

However, if values are checked that do not match results I get the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in Server.exe
>   Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
    public int CheckLoginCredentials(String username,string password)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * from testTable.user WHERE username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "'";
        int Count = -1;

        //Open Connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //Create Mysql Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            //ExecuteScalar will return one value
            try
            {
                Count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar() + "");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw e;
            }
            //close Connection
            this.CloseConnection();

            return Count;
        }
        else
        {
            return Count;
        }
    }
```

I attempted to throw the exception, but it crashes the server. How can I gracefully solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `SELECT Count(*)` here in this scenario;

> [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) will Executes the query, and returns the first column
>   of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional
>   columns or rows are ignored.

And one more common suggestion; Use parameterized queries to avoid SqlInjection; so The command Definition will be like the following:

```
        string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) from testTable.user WHERE username=@username and password=@password";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
```

Now the command is ready for execution. As MSDN suggested `ExecuteScalar()` will return an `object` that we need to convert to an integer, but in this case, the `count()` will always return an integer value(`0` if result is null), Hence the output of `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` will be a `boxed integer`. so the query execution will be as follows:

```
   int Count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Also, change the code to this: `Count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: You don't need to `ToString()` and then parse the string.. that's wasted work. The result is already a boxed integer, you simply need to cast to int as above :)

Comment: @un-lucky great answer. Parametrized queries is a double win for me, never knew that. I wish I could double vote you. Works like a char.